# Scheme cons and length

Tags: scheme, maxlength, cons

I'm studying scheme and I have just encountered my first problem:

```
(define x (cons (list 1 2) (list 3 4)))
(length x)
3
```

why the output is 3 and not 2? I have displayed x

```
((1 2) 3 4)
```

why is like that and not `((1 2) . (3 4))` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's easier to see this way.

You have:

```
(cons (list 1 2) (list 3 4))
```

If you

```
(define one-two (list 1 2))
```

you have

```
(cons one-two (list 3 4))
```

which is equivalent to

```
(cons one-two (cons 3 (cons 4 '())))
```

or

```
(list one-two 3 4)
```

which is

```
((1 2) 3 4)
```

Comment: what I don't get is from `(cons a (cons 3 (cons 4 '())))` to `(list a 3 4)`.
Shouldn't a cons cell end with a `'()` to be a list?

Comment: No, a list is a cons cell where its `cdr` is a list, and `'()` is the empty list.

Comment: So `(cons 4 '())` is a list because its `cdr` is a list, the empty list. And `(cons 3 (cons 4 '()))` is a list because its `cdr` is a list, the list from the first sentence. And `(cons a (cons 3 (cons 4 '())))` is a list because its `cdr` is the list from the second sentence.

Comment: I can see the light!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

List is the basic data structure of scheme.
Cons is used for making a pair of objects. List is the chain of cons.
eg. list (1 2 3 4) is same as (cons 1(cons 2(cons 3(cons 4 '())))).
See the block pointer representation for make it clear